# i want to add a checkbox to buttons

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox


class Ckbox(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    cc =[]
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(5):
            self.bb = Button()
            self.cq = CheckBox()
            self.cc.append(self.cq)
            self.add_widget(self.bb)
           self.add_widget(self.cq)

class Ckboxapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Ckbox()
Ckboxapp().run()
```

from the above code, i get this[image]

but i want the checkbox and button to be together so i add the button variable to the add widget as self.bb.add_widget(self.cq) and got this[image]

the second image show the checkbox attached to the button but only showing on the last button only. i want itlike in the second iamge but i want it to be on all the buttons. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put each `CheckBox`/`Button` pair in another `BoxLayout`, I think you will get what you want. Try this:

```
class Ckbox(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(5):
            bl = BoxLayout()
            bb = Button(text='Button ' + str(i), size_hint_x=0.85)
            cq = CheckBox(size_hint_x=0.15)
            bl.add_widget(cq)
            bl.add_widget(bb)
            self.add_widget(bl)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works just fine for what I want to do